# Unable to vote!

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, ios-app, per-site-meta

Since the latest release, I am unable to vote since it keeps telling me I am not a member on that site (as you can see I answered a question on MSO just a few hours back and I am a member for a long time already).

Note that I can only reproduce this on MSO and Meta Seasoned Advice, not on SO or MSE. Can anyone reproduce this on other meta sites?

> [image: Broken]

Please fix my vote button!

---

- App Version: 1.4.0.241
- Device: iPhone7,2
- OS Version: Version 9.1 (Build 13B143)

Comment: Just checking, you're not out of votes? That would be amazing on meta.se, but you never know....

Comment: Nope. MSE works btw, MSO doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

There are actually two problems here:

1. I accidentally removed meta sites from the network user cache.
2. Even though I removed the meta sites, things should have worked when you tapped Join.  It should have gotten back a network user and stuck it in the list.  Unfortunately, when I checked to see if it was in the list, I was accidentally checking if `self == self` so it never got inserted.

Comment: So, is self really equal to self? ;)

Comment: "I was accidentally checking if `self == self`" lol, is it even valid :D